# how to pass json object to bootstrap-table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-table

From the the controller I am passing a json encoded object to my view. In the view i have used bootstrap table to display the data. However in the table it show No matching records found. Please help.
here is my controller
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRugD.png)

here is my view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8H4G.png)

Comment: Are you using http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/?

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap-table. have also refrence it on my master.blade.php.

Comment: did u get an answer to this question? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your model is *roommaster*. To get Eloquent model to json use 
`$roommaster->toJson()` 
because `json_encode($roommaster)` needs $roommaster to be an array and in your case is an object

Comment: yes my model is roommaster. and the code you mentioned gives and error "Call to a member function toJson() on a non-object"

Comment: can you show me the code of your model? I need to know what RoomAvailability return

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use DB;

class roommaster extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'roommasters';

    public static function RoomAvailability($checkin,$checkout) {
     $roommaster = DB::select('call RoomAvailability('. $checkin .','. $checkout .')');
     //$roommaster = DB::select('select * from roommasters');
     return $roommaster;
    }
}

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use DB;

class roommaster extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'roommasters';

    public static function RoomAvailability($checkin,$checkout) {
     $roommaster = DB::select('call RoomAvailability('. $checkin .','. $checkout .')');
     //$roommaster = DB::select('select * from roommasters');
     return $roommaster;
    }
}

Comment: are `$checkin` and `$checkout` string? because you might want to get them into quotes for your query: `DB::select('call RoomAvailability(\''. $checkin .'\',\''. $checkout .'\')');`

Comment: `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use DB;

class roommaster extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'roommasters';

    public static function RoomAvailability($checkin,$checkout) {
     $roommaster = DB::select('call RoomAvailability('. $checkin .','. $checkout .')');
     //$roommaster = DB::select('select * from roommasters');
     return $roommaster;
    }
}`

Comment: i am able to retrieve the data. it display if i use foreach and list the data. but it does not show in the bootstrap table data-url. if I view the page source it does show the value

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the source code of the page the table is on to see if the code is outputting JSON to data-url?

If it is, I think the issue isn't with the PHP code but the table itself. Try adding this to the blade template and getting rid of data-url from your table.

Code for table:

```
<table class="table table-hover" data-click-to-select="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" data-checkbox="true">ID</th>
            <th data-field="roomname">Room name</th>
            <th data-field="Desc">Description</th>
            <th data-field="price">Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Code to populate table with data:

```
<script>
var $table = $('.table.table-hover');
$(function () {
    var data = {!! $roomname !!};
    $table.bootstrapTable({data: data});
});
</script>
```

Comment: i tried your script. but no luck. and yes if i see the page source it does show the json value in data-url

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()                 
var $table = $('.table.table-hover');
$(function () {
var data = [{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;roomname&quot;:&quot;smNsspx6u9&quot;,&quot;Desc&quot;:&quot;tYn6aWKXRV&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:300},{&quot;id&quot;:2,&quot;roomname&quot;:&quot;DktjLKUlzA&quot;,&quot;Desc&quot;:&quot;dPOvOCEfhF&quot;,&quot;price&quot;:300}];
$table.bootstrapTable({data: data});
});

          



      });
  </script>

Comment: Hm, that's strange - I used http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/13/ as a base right from the official sites examples section. There are more examples here http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/ if you want to have a look. Data-url expects the data given to be a URL where the json data is displayed, so you can always pass a URL where you are displaying the JSON data.

Edit: I just saw your reply -Try {!! $roomname !!} instead?

Comment: Its strange for me too. As you have said have removed one of the { and put !!. But stil it is not showing the data in the table. Plz suggest me some help... Will really appriciate

Comment: Is console returning anything and are you calling the script after jquery? If we can't get the table to work this way you can always set up a route in Laravel which returns json_encode($roommaster) and set data-url to point to it

Comment: hey its now showing undefined variable roomname for {!! roomname!!}

Comment: Did you add the $? Sorry I can't help further - I've tested the above code with a sample JSON object generated from Laravel in the same way you are, and it works for me. It might be worth asking the question again with a javascript or jquery tag.

Comment: sorry i mistake. What i am trying to achieve is user select the date and click the show button. so in the show button i m using post method to get the selected date and through route i m calling the controller and returning the output in the view through json_encoded

Comment: Try getting rid of data-toggle="table", too. I think that's the issue. In my test environment, I wasn't using data-toggle="table", but once I  added it it stopped working and returned the 'No results found' error. Hope that helps!

Comment: just want to mention did not work with data-url. but worked with the script